# How to handle the large website rss feed

Tags: design-patterns, large-scale-project, rss

Portal website usually have very large number of posts. For example I have 50,000 posts in website. I even created the google sitemap as chunks and included it in main site map file. But I have no idea how to deal with RSS feed.

50,000 posts in RSS feed file size will be very huge, how to handle the situation?

Comment: Do you really need to store ALL posts inside RSS feed? I'd just leave there only last part of it and update it every couple of days. If you have some sort of taxonomy(categories/tags) in your website, you could divide RSS feeds by category.

Comment: I like to know is that important to include all the post in RSS feed.

Comment: Generally storing the feed of latest 20 or 30 posts is enough for easy parsing of rss feed. Its not important to have all posts in rss feed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking if it is important to include all links in RSS - look at other huge services - nytimes.com displays only 25 links in it's feed. It's up to RSS readers software to fetch your feed often enough to get all  I guess.